# The most efficient way to compare 2 aggregates (set of vertices) in Gremlin Query Language

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

What's the most efficient way to compare 2 aggregates (set of vertices) and see if they contain the exact same results?

Using this doesn't seem to work:

`.where(select('aggregate1').is(eq('aggregate2')))`

aggregate1 and aggregate2 each one contains a bunch of vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating equality of two sets should work, but they will both likely need to be ordered sets.  Examples

```
g.inject([1,2,3]).is(eq([1,2,3]))
```

... provides a match and returns ...

```
1   [1, 2, 3]
```

However, if I change the order of the second set, as in...

```
g.inject([3,2,1]).is(eq([1,2,3]))
```

... then nothing gets returned (showing non-equivalence).

You would need to insert an `order(local)` into the query to ensure the first set is ordered to match the second:

```
g.inject([3,2,1]).order(local).is(eq([1,2,3]))
```

Returns:

```
1   [1, 2, 3]
```

As an aside...

If looking for the difference between the two, you could use `where(within('x'))` or `where(without('x'))` as a way to see the intersection or complement respectively.

As an example using the airroutes dataset, if I wanted to find the common destination airports flying from MLI and ABE, I could use the following query:

```
g.V().hasLabel('airport').has('code','MLI').
    out('route').
    aggregate('mlir').limit(1).
    V().hasLabel('airport').has('code','ABE').
    out('route').
    aggregate('aber').
    where(within('mlir')).values('code')
```

Returns result:

```
1   PIE
2   ATL
3   ORD
4   SFB
5   DTW
```

If I wanted to see which destination airports are in one set but not the other, I could use:

```
g.V().hasLabel('airport').has('code','MLI').
    out('route').
    aggregate('mlir').limit(1).
    V().hasLabel('airport').has('code','ABE').
    out('route').
    aggregate('aber').
    where(without('mlir')).values('code')
```

Result:

```
1   CLT
2   MYR
3   BNA
4   FLL
5   PGD
6   PHL
```

Comment: Thanks Taylor, yes `eq` doesn't help but using `where(without(` solved it for me.

Comment: To be  specific, I had to use a `choose` combined with `where`, `without` and `count`